# Using 6x58W fluorescent lamps instead of 6x55W, what could possibly go wrong?

Tags: light, watts, lamp, fluorescent-lamp

I'm planning to buy a fluorescent photography lighting head, but the manufacturer specified it uses 6x55W lamps, but I want to use Philips Graphica 58W lamps. 3 watts more per lamp, doesn't look like a big increase over the limit, but could it damage the lamps so they will burn out quicker? Or this is within some safe range? 
Maybe it's a duplicate, but I haven't got any luck with Google, and the lighting head is not that cheap, it's $300, and I need two of them, so no way I'm going to test it out myself, without knowing if it will work.

Comment: Someone wants to close this, I think that's an interesting question though. I can't answer you on why it would/would not work, my advice is phone/email the lighting head manufacturer and ask them. For 300 bucks I expect a decent customer service.

Comment: The problem is, they are located in Hong Kong, so I'm not sure, if they have a decent customer service. Well, I could give it a try, or wait, if someone eventually answers my question.

Comment: Sending them an email is the fastest and safest way to get the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to right know. Hong Kong companies, should know English better than the mainland China I guess, so may be, it will be faster.

Comment: If you don't expect anything you can only be positively surprised. Once I bought a GPS module from a china website, I needed a new firmware for it, I wrote to the company, compiled a module and a guy over there wrote the firmware for me, with my spec, for free. Give them a possibilty

Comment: Yeah, that's certainly more than you could expect, for free. The big western companies, usually don't modify the firmware for their gear, for request, hehe.

Comment: All care no responsibility, but, if they are both "just plain fluorescent bulbs" I'd be very surprised if it did not work acceptably well. The difference of about 6% MORE in bulb power rating is within the variations liable to be experienced due to grid voltage fluctuations. You can find grids operating at 220 VAC, 230 VAC and even 240 VAC and these variations are a substantial part of the difference you are talking about. I HAVE seen equipment with settings for 220/230/240 volts, but never for fluorescent lamps.

Answer (score 1):

With no information about the fixture (not even a link?), it's really impossible to speculate.

However, based on the [bulb you mention](http://download.p4c.philips.com/l4b/9/928045296581_eu/928045296581_eu_pss_aenaa.pdf), and the fact that it uses an external ballast, I can say that probably nothing bad will happen.

It's the ballast that controls the current through a fluorescent lamp, and therefore its power consumption. So, since the ballast is part of the fixture, it's very likely that the fixture will simply operate the bulbs at 55W, causing nothing more than a 5% drop from their nominal light output.

Comment: There are not so many details about the fixture, well like you said, it says it has built-in ballast. http://www.falconeyes.com.hk/Product.aspx?id=104

Comment: Based on the fuzzy picture, I'm not sure the bulbs you're proposing are physically compatible. Those look like U-shaped CFL bulbs, not straight 4-pin bulbs.